# Barred crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**1** 47 Across writer's signature train (6)
**6** A letter to Ms. White (not Ms. Landers) shows initial spirit (6)
**11** You call this a party? You are sad (4)
**13** Don't need anything crazy (4)
**15** Sectarian who is convinced by speech (8)
**17** Talk about *Rocky* Ⅰ–Ⅳ (4)
**18** Almost foils evil plans: heads east to Spain (5)
**19** Close to the line? Capital! Stop at nothing (5)
**21** Partner to black follower of Yan's (3)
**22** Develop new cybernetics reusing computers (their cores) (5)
**23** Check out a sort of doc (3)
**24** Put out, conclusively, the animal that goes after the head! (7)
**27** Costly defense, I hear (4)
**29** A flyer (not a flying mammal!) returns, becoming a swimmer (4)
**32** Best-ever opening scenes lead to Emmy (7)
**34** Lost at War by placing a low number and only then an ace, after seeing a high number (3)
**35** The user-facing parts of R, ECMAScript, Python, Lisp, sed, …! (5)
**37** So prompt (3)
**39** Welcome back! Grab a letter (5)
**40** Going backwards, steer into a cheer leader and a script kiddie (5)
**41** Transfer/catalytic ribonucleic complex (4)
**43** See a quotation of, perhaps, *New York 2140* (8)
**44** Perhaps Greenwich time, for one (4)
**45** Act the boss at the newspaper: read backward and forward (4)
**46** Spiritual leader gone south for some disgusting waste (6)
**47** In retrospect, wino, smashed… he shouldn't have drunk any wine (6)

#### Down

**2** Notice home redesign (5)
**3** Mr. Edmonds's choice joint has "killa" at center (2,4)
**4** German reference of defective English (5)
**5** Identifying sign of angry spa clientele (7,5)
**6** These, cloches? Weird! (12)
**7** Soused, i.e. dumb-drunk (6)
**8** Called Sanka "pointless" (3)
**9** W.C.'s a bother: it has a clog (5)
**10** Fake ego-abnegation of Opus Dei members (6)
**12** An advantage following the queen's gambit (4)
**14** Love to go through wood (5)
**16** Online Test match (5)
**20** Toerags' odd messes? (4)
**25** Northern Ireland uprising here! (4)
**26** Tip of my tongue's to stick to something (5)
**28** The essence of Larry Bird is contrition (6)
**30** Commute to work, perhaps, from home (5)
**31** A limb (foot) wearing an Air Jordan is close to this (6)
**33** Sprite's sweet treats have captivated a president and a general secretary (6)
**34** A production made of the Rev. Spooner's failure to hit the white ball (5)
**36** That girl had a splendid vacation with that guy as guest (4)
**37** Contrary to popular belief, not only females were punished here: males got tortured (5)
**38** Endless protection afforded by apartment (5)
**42** It is likely to be eaten — eaten by grues (3)

---

<sub>Credit: The layout (blank grid) is slightly altered from one by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solved grid should look like this:

> [image: Completed grid]

Clue explanations:

> **Across:**
>  1 **[Samson] writer**'s signature train (6) **[HANDEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_(Handel))** = HAND (signature) + [EL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevated_railway) (train)
>  6 A letter to Ms. White (not Ms. Landers) shows initial **spirit** (6) **[CHIVAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivas_Regal)** = CHI + V(-ann)A + S(-hows)
>  11 You call this a party? You are **sad** (4) **DOUR** = DO (party) + U R (you are)
>  13 Don't need anything **crazy** (4) **AMOK** = AM OK
>  15 **Sectarian** who is convinced by speech (8) **SADDUCEE** = “seducee”
>  17 **Talk** about Rocky Ⅰ–Ⅳ (4) **BLAB** = BALB(-oa)<
>  18 **Almost foils** evil plans: heads east to Spain (5) **EPEES** = E_ P_ + E (east) + ES (Spain)
>  19 **Close to the line? Capital!** Stop at nothing (5) **QUITO** = QUIT + O (Quito is a capital city close to 'the line', i.e. the Equator)
>  21 **Partner to black** / **follower of Yan's** (3) **TAN** = ddef ([Black & Tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_and_Tans), [Yan tan tethera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yan_tan_tethera))
>  22 **Develop** new cybernetics reusing computers (their cores) (5) **ENSUE** = _E_ _N_ _S_ _U_ _E_
>  23 **Check out** / **a sort of doc** (3) **VET** = ddef
>  24 Put out, conclusively, the animal that goes after the head! (7) **DELOUSE** = D(_E _L)OUSE &lit!
>  27 **Costly** defense, I hear (4) **DEAR** = D (defence) + EAR (I hear)
>  29 A flyer (not a flying mammal!) returns, becoming **a swimmer** (4) **ORCA** = ACRO(-bat)<
>  32 **Best**-ever opening scenes lead to Emmy (7) **ECLIPSE** = E(-ver) + CLIPS (scenes) + E(-mmy)
>  34 **Lost at War** by placing a low number and only then an ace, after seeing a high number (3) **MIA** = M (a high number) + I (a low number) + A (ace)
>  35 The user-facing parts of R, ECMAScript, Python, Lisp, sed, …! (5) **[REPLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)** = R_ E_ P_ L_ S_ &lit!
>  37 So prompt (3) **SIC** = ddef
>  39 **Welcome** back! Grab a letter (5) **UNBAN** = (NAB + NU)<
>  40 Going backwards, steer into a cheer leader and **a script kiddie** (5) **[HAXOR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haxor)** = R(OX)AH<
>  41 **Transfer**/catalytic ribonucleic complex (4) **CRIB** = _C RIB_
>  43 See a quotation of, **perhaps, *New York 2140*** (8) **DATELINE** = DATE (See) + LINE (a quotation)
>  44 Perhaps Greenwich time, for **one** (4) **UNIT** = UNI (perhaps Greenwich) + T (time)
>  45 **Act** the boss at the newspaper: read backward and forward (4) **DEED** = ED< + ED
>  46 Spiritual leader gone south for **some disgusting waste** (6) **SEWAGE** = (n → S)EWAGE
>  47 In retrospect, wino, smashed… **he shouldn't have drunk any wine** (6) **[SAMSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson)** = (_NO SMAS_)<
>
>  **Down:**
>  2 Notice home **redesign** (5) **ADAPT** = AD (notice) + APT (home, i.e. ‘apartment’)
>  3 **Mr. Edmonds's choice** joint has "killa" at center (2,4) **[NO DEAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_or_No_Deal_(British_game_show))** = NODE (joint) + (-h)A(-s) + (-ki)L(-la)
>  4 **German reference** of defective English (5) **DUDEN** = DUD (defective) + EN (English)
>  5 **Identifying sign** of angry spa clientele (7,5) **LICENSEPLATE** = SPACLIENTELE*
>  6 These, cloches? Weird! (12) **CHEESECLOTHS** = THESECLOCHES* &lit!
>  7 **Soused**, i.e. dumb-drunk (6) **IMBUED** = IEDUMB*
>  8 **Called** Sanka "pointless" (3) **AKA** = (-s)A(-n)KA
>  9 W.C.'s a bother: it has **a clog** (5) **[SABOT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sabot)** = _S A BOT_
>  10 **Fake** ego-abnegation of Opus Dei members (6) **PSEUDO** = OPUSDE(-i_*
>  12 An advantage following the queen's **gambit** (4) **RUSE** = R (‘regina’ i.e. queen) + USE (advantage)
>  14 Love to go through **wood** (5) **OLIVE** = O (Love) + LIVE (to go through)
>  16 Online Test **match** (5) **EQUAL** = E (Online) + QUAL (test, short for ‘qualification’)
>  20 Toerags' odd **messes?** (4) **TEAS** = T(-o)E(-r)A(-g)S
>  25 Northern Ireland uprising here! (4) **ERIN** = (N + IRE)< &lit! (another name for ‘Ireland’)
>  26 **Tip** of my tongue's to stick to something (5) **UPEND** = "Append" ('to stick to something') *[thanks @SQLnoob in comments]*
>  28 The essence of Larry Bird is **contrition** (6) **REGRET** = (-la)R(-ry) + EGRET (bird)
>  30 Commute to work, perhaps, from **home** (5) **CABIN** = CAB IN
>  31 A limb (foot) wearing an Air **Jordan is close to this** (6) **ARABIA** = AR(A + _B)IA
>  33 **Sprite's** sweet treats have captivated a president and a general secretary (6) **PIXIE’S** = PI(XI)ES
>  34 **A production** made of the Rev. Spooner's failure to hit the white ball (5) **MUCUS** = Spooner(cue miss)
>  36 **That girl had** a splendid vacation with that guy as guest (4) **SHE’D** = S(-plendi)D containing HE
>  37 **Contrary to popular belief, not only females were punished here:** males got tortured (5) **[SALEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_witch_trials)** = MALES*
>  38 Endless protection afforded by **apartment** (5) **CONDO** = CONDO(-m)
>  42 **It is likely to be eaten** — eaten by grues (3) **RUE** = _RUE_

Comment: Well done! You've missed the wordplay for 24A, 46A, 3D, & 26D. In 32A, "lead to" grabbing the initial was the intention, but your way works as well.

Comment: Aha, I see 24A now! Yes, those other 3 I mentioned in my preamble as being uncertain of the wordplay - I'm mulling them over still but am happy for others to chime in in comments with ideas...

Comment: I'm really bad at these, but maybe 26D indicates a word that sounds like (my tongue's) append (stick to something)?

Comment: @SQLnoob You're bang on! "Append", yes - thanks :)

Comment: @msh210 I think all is now as per what you expected (hopefully!)

Comment: Yes, indeed! Checkmark incoming…